# So I've got intrinsic magic resistance?

Tags: nethack

I'm a gnomish Wizard in Nethack 3.6.0.

In Minetown, a werewolf attacked me and conveyed lycanthropy to me. I was wearing my starting cloak of magic resistance when transformed to a wolf, dropping my weapons and armors on the ground. To get rid of lycanthropy, I rushed to the temple(luckily enough, it's co-aligned), sacrificed some wolf corpses and prayed to my god. By the time I went back and tried to equip myself with those dropped items, my cloak of magic resistance has gone!

I thought it might be stolen or picked up by a random monster nearby, so I killed all monster on that level except shopkeepers and the priest(I'm sure there are no monsters left, because I have intrinsic telepathy), but I still couldn't find the cloak.

Then I thought, may be I've got intrinsic magic resistance? To (dis)prove that, I stripped myself naked and zapped myself with a force bolt spell and a magic missile spell. The only message I received was "boing", and I didn't lose any Hp, so it seems that my guess is proved.

However, as far as I know, magic resistance isn't an intrinsic. Is it true that I got intrinsic magic resistance through a hidden mechanism, simply because I wore a cloak of magic resistance when being transformed to a wolf?

PS: Although I have magic resistance now, I still want to get my cloak back, for I've already enchanted it. Any ideas about how to find it?

Comment: Do you have the text of when you got transformed and your stuff was unequipped ?

Comment: You're not going to get the cloak back; transforming into a wolf destroys anything you're wearing on your torso. The MR may or may not be a bug. Are you wielding Magicbane? Carrying any other artifacts that might convey MR?

Comment: @Fana Too many things happened after my transformation to a wolf, so the text has already been overridden by other stuff...

Comment: @geoffspear Oh! Magicbane! Yes I **was** wielding that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was stated in the comments, there are artifacts that convey magic resistance. Since you said that you were wielding magicbane, that's where your magic resistance came from.